# You must prepare against dangerous lie ahead

Tags: grammar

> You must prepare against dangerous lie ahead.

Is this sentence correct?

I think if this one is correct, then it means like: You must prepare against dangerous situation beforehand.

lie is also a noun: (n) lie (position or manner in which something is situated)

http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=lie&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=

Comment: Absolutely everything that could possibly be wrong with a sentence is wrong with it. You prepare *for* something, not 'against' it. "Dangerous" is an adjective - does an adjective lie ahead? How can you prepare for an adjective?

Comment: @Astralbee be nice; it’s really not that bad.

Comment: @Fivesideddice It is. I can't even tell if they actually mean "danger lies ahead" or that there are lies (mistruths) that are dangerous. Either way, asking if something is correct is off-topic here, so unless there is more to the question it ought to be closed.

Comment: @Astralbee The "lie" they are using is not a verb, but an actual noun, similar to "lay" as in "lay of the land".  I've seen it used in extremely dense academic papers that are incredibly hard to read.  A non-native speaker should probably not try using this usage, of course.

Comment: Lie is used in golf, as in the lie of the ball. It's hard to fit the sentence into this context though.

Comment: Thank you @Peter, yes, golf is another usage of this kind of "lie".  It does not apply to general situations, but very specific kinds of situations.

Comment: What do you think about 'prepare against disaster'? Are you guys for it or against it?Therefore, it is urgent for us to prepare against a disaster.

Comment: @Brandon It's archaic, and we don't usually say that anymore, as I said in my answer below.  You could "Prepare against the chance of disaster", but even this is a very formal phrase not in common use.

Comment: Now I got the answer it's archaic.

Answer (score 2):

> You must prepare against dangerous lie ahead.

This sentence is not correct.

- Despite Astralbee's comment, "prepare against" is not *necessarily* wrong, but it is an older form rarely used after the early 1800s according to [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prepare+against&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprepare%20against%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cprepare%20against%3B%2Cc0), which matches my native perception of the form.  I would expect to find it used in poetry, not prose.  The proper modern form is "prepare for".
- Your noun requires an article, otherwise the "zero article" is used, which is only for abstract nouns and proper names.  So it would have to be "***a*** dangerous {noun}" or "***the*** dangerous {noun}".
- The meaning of "lie" *can* mean a situation, but using this definition is definitely not as simple as substituting "lie" for "situation".  It is an *extremely* technical usage not in use *at all* by the general population of native English speakers.  To put it into context, it is a MORE formal and MORE technical version of "lay", as in the the phrase "lay of the land", which is already a very formal and situational word not in use by the general population.  Most English speakers will *not*, in any way, understand this usage.  I would **strongly** suggest using "situation" or another more specific word for the exact kind of situation, such as "battle", "tournament", or "meeting".

The corrected sentence would be:

> You must prepare for the dangerous situation ahead.

Comment: Thx. I think your answer is helpful but not the one I sought after.

Comment: Your question was "is this correct", and the answer is "no".  I specified why the answer is no, and I offered a corrected statement.  Could you please refine your question so that we can answer it better for you?

Comment: I got the answer Richard. It's archaic and not commonly used these days.

Comment: I have only ever heard lie of the land in the UK.